# Add event participant names to my invoice

Tags: civievent, invoice

We have an invoice created as part of our registration for events.  It picks up the price set field - eg. BBGA Member ticket, Non member ticket etc and shows that under description.  this is out of the box stuff.

Is there a way to edit the invoice template to include the participant names.  This is so the invoice shows who the tickets were purchased for. (I'm using the workflow invoice template)

The event is set up for multiple participants recording their name, company and email addresses as well as the person registering them.

THank you in advance

Comment: Browse the tokens dropdown which appears in the template edit screen! If I should guess and If the event participation is the token context, I'd start with {contact.display_name}. If that's not right, I would track/detect the available tokens in a tiny php extension. But the core team at civicrm mattermost may know this.